# SQL optimized IO calls (comparing mutiple IOs or single IO with huge data)

Tags: sql, io, query-optimization, mysql-python, sql-optimization

I have a SQL table `Student`. It has 30 columns (properties) for each student.

I need 10 properties in a SQL query.

Which one is better approach ?

1. `q1 = 'SELECT * FROM STUDENTS where uid in %s'%tuple(list1);`
2. for k in properties:

   ```
    `q1 = 'SELECT k FROM STUDENTS where uid in %s'%tuple(list1);`
   ```

Mainly comparison is between single I/O with huge amount of data or multiple I/O with less amount of data

I think the 1st approach is better as in single IO all data will be loaded to memory then iterating over it is faster in memory

Comment: If you only need 10 out of 30 fields, why does option 1 select all 30?

Comment: This is one of those cases where the most accurate response will be whatever you determine from trying it yourself, in your own environment, under your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
select k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6, k7, k8, k9, k10 from STUDENTS where uid in %s'%tuple(list1);
```

Comment: That i know. But due to some reasons i wanted to compare option mentioned in question. Let suppose I have constraint , due to which i cant use your approach

Comment: Really you can do a * but not that due to a constaint